# WordPress wp_enque_scripts doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I've created a child of a WordPress theme and now I'm trying to insert custom JavaScript into the home page by modifying functions.php of the child. However, my script is not being loaded and I'm not sure why. I've inserted 'echo' statements into the php code and it seems like

```
add_action( 'wp_enque_scripts', 'video_bg', 10);
```

fails to call

```
video_bg()
```

Here's the functions.php of my child:

```
<?php


add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'post_theme_setup' );

if ( !function_exists( 'post_theme_setup' )):
function post_theme_setup(){

    function video_bg() {
        wp_enque_script( 'myVideo', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/JS/filmScript.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', false );
        echo '<script>console.log("Script added?")</script>';
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enque_scripts', 'video_bg', 10);
    echo '<script>console.log("Loop Entered")</script>';

}
endif;
```

And here's what the console is telling me:

```
Loop Entered                                      (index):1 
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1    jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1&nocache=1:2
```

Could anyone please tell me why video_bg() never gets called? Or is the problem in something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function isn't called when you added it some add_action, there are 2 possible cases:
1. You entered wrong action/filter hook name.
2. Your loaded page doesn't trigger that hook.

In this case you did the 1st. There is not a hook called: wp_enque_scripts, there is not a function called wp_enque_scripts.
Change them to wp_enqueue_scripts.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'video_bg', 10);
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'post_theme_setup' );

if ( !function_exists( 'post_theme_setup' )):
function post_theme_setup(){

    function video_bg() {
        wp_enqueue_scripts( 'myVideo', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/JS/filmScript.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', false );
        echo '<script>console.log("Script added?")</script>';
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'video_bg', 10);
    echo '<script>console.log("Loop Entered")</script>';

}
endif;
```

You can also optimize your code like that:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'post_theme_setup' );

if ( !function_exists( 'post_theme_setup' )):
function post_theme_setup(){
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'video_bg', 10);
    echo '<script>console.log("Loop Entered")</script>';

}
endif;

  function video_bg() {
        wp_enqueue_scripts( 'myVideo', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/JS/filmScript.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', false );
        echo '<script>console.log("Script added?")</script>';
    }
```

Comment: Wow, that's embarrassing, haha. Thank you! However, now WordPress seems to ignore functions.php of the child altogether. None of the "echo" statements print to the console. Even when I reduce the code just to a `<?php tag` and an `echo` line - it still doesn't show. Might not be code-related - maybe WordPress is just bugging out. What should I check? Thanks a million!

Comment: May be post_theme_setup is declared in parent theme before this, that's why.   Try rename that function in child theme. And actually you don't need it.

Comment: Actually, there is still a problm. The echo thing was just a Firefox console issue - works in Chrome. The `wp_enqueue_scripts( 'myVideo', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/JS/filmScript.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', false );` line  though causes an internal server error. Not sure why. When I comment it out - everything loads no problem